# Google location history

Tags: google-maps, google

How can I translate my Google location history (latitude/longitude) with timestamps to a map that will show me where each pair of coordinates is located?

Comment: you just want to display the points on a map? I did a small analysis on my locations for a USA cross country I did I few years back, it uses python and postgis do you want me to post it?

Answer (score 4):

You can see your location history on a map using your [Timeline](https://www.google.com.au/maps/timeline?pb).

You can [download](https://takeout.google.com/) your location history as KML and then view in any GIS or Google Earth.